# Understanding client and server sockets

Tags: java, sockets

i have a question.
i do not fully understand how client and server sockets work?
what i understand is
when a server socket is created it has many ports that can be opened .socket objects are created on the server side which connects to different ports of the server socket.the socket connected to the server socket connects to the client socket and completes the connection?

am i right or wrong?

```
    public class TryThreads extends Thread 
    {
    private int Portnumber;
    private static String inputLine;
    public TryThreads(int portNumber)

    {
        Portnumber = portNumber; 
        setDaemon(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //create three threads
        Thread first = new TryThreads(63400);
        Thread second = new TryThreads(63401);
        first.start();
        second.start();
        //third.start();
        System.out.println("ending main");      
        return;     
    }

    public void run()
    {
        //System.out.println("one socket port opened");
        try
        {
            System.out.println("one socket port opened");
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Portnumber);
            System.out.println("one socket port opened");
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println("ending main2");
            //System.out.println("one socket port opened");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                 System.out.println(inputLine);             
            }           
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {           
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    }
```

And the Client

```
public class client     
{
private static PrintWriter printWriter;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",63400);
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);       
        printWriter.println("Hello Socket");
        printWriter.println("EYYYYYAAAAAAAA!!!!");
        socket.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);
    }       
}   
}
```

Comment: You can simply read this article and review your code. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html or that http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24600/Using-Sockets-in-Java-Server
The best way to learn something is to do it by yourselve then you will remember more.

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/Socket.java.html or http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Socket.java

Comment: i want to see the methods definition of the classes Socket and Server socket , is it possible ?

Comment: So there it is ServerSocket implementation: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/ServerSocket.java.html

And Socket implementation:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/Socket.java.html

Comment: Uncelar what your code has to do with it, or indeed what you're really asking.

Answer (score 0):

Port number you provide for ServerSocket is server socket's listening port for the incoming request whereas port number you specified in the client side code is server side listening port your client is going to connect.

Please check other server side socket examples including this one.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Check how server socket's accept() works and what's the return value of it.

So basically,
Server side socket has created and bound to specific port for incoming request listening.
Client connect to the listening port of the server socket. ( binding to client is not necessary, it's randomly chosen )
ServerSocket create Socket instance which is connected to client side.
You might want to give this server side socket to separate Thread(or worker or whatever) since you want ServerSocket to keep listen incoming connection.

Comment: The listening port and the port the client is trying to connect to are the same thing.

Comment: Yes you did. Read your first sentence. The `whereas` is meaningless.

Comment: @EJP "whereas client side's port number is the port that client is actually trying to connect. => port number being used in client side source code to connect server side" Is this make things more clear? Looks like my writing was ambiguous.

Comment: So you think they're different, and they're not, which is what I said originally, and what you claim you're agreeing with. Make up your mind.

Comment: @EJP I'm saying client side specify remote side's listening port whereas server side specify its listening port. I was trying to explain different perspective between server and client side. And YES it does mean same port number of server side. If you still don't understand, that's fine too. Maybe my english isn't good enough for you to understand it.

Comment: @EJP You are trying to believe that I'm saying different than what you said earlier in the comment.

Comment: @EJP well, if I switch "whereas" to "and", will you satisfy?

Comment: There's no point in saying the same thing twice, whatever the two are separated by. It continues to give the impression that there are two different things where there aren't.

Answer (score 0):

> what i understand is when a server socket is created it has many ports that can be opened.

No. One port.

> socket objects are created on the server side which connects to different ports of the server socket.

No. One port.

> the socket connected to the server socket connects to the client socket and completes the connection?

The *client* connects to the *server*, and not to a socket but a *port*. The client's end of the connection is represented by a socket. The server's end represents another socket.

Answer (score -1):

Server socket is listening on specific port ex 80.
when a server accept a connection will create an accepted socket with a specific port that can direct the connection with client

Comment: With the *same* port, not 'a specific port'.